# How to delete a cell inside a imageview?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I need a way to delete the cell that inside the imageview mockCell.  Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
          //Create mock cell to drag around
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.highlighted = NO;
        [mockCell removeFromSuperview];
        mockCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        mockCell.image = [self imageFromCell:cell];
        mockCenter = mockCell.center;
        [self.collectionView addSubview:mockCell];
        [UIView
         animateWithDuration:0.3
         animations:^{
             mockCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
         }
         completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

You should also delete it from your datasource when you do this: it's good to keep the DataSource and the CollectionView in sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
 I have done this for deleting multiple images at a time.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView == deletePhotoConfirmAlert) {
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    // Permission to delete the button is granted here.
    NSArray *selectedItemsIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

   // Delete the items from the data source.
    [self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];
}
}
}

// This method is for deleting the selected images from the data source array
-(void)deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:(NSArray  *)itemPaths
{
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSIndexPath *itemPath  in itemPaths) {
[indexSet addIndex:itemPath.row];

}
[self.images removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet]; // self.images is my data source

}
```

Edit this Method if you are using StoryBoard

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSArray *indexpaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
DetailViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
dest.imageName = [self.images objectAtIndex:[[indexpaths objectAtIndex:0] row]];

}
```